# must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard in swift

Tags: ios

My model:

```
  enum NHAnswerType:Int
    {

        case NHAnswerCheckboxButton = 1
        case NHAnswerRadioButton = 2
        case NHAnswerSmileyButton = 3
        case NHAnswerStarRatingButton = 4
        case NHAnswerTextButton = 5
    }


    class NH_QuestionListModel: NSObject {

        var dataListArray33:[NH_OptionsModel] = []


        var id:Int!
        var question:String!
        var buttontype:String!
        var options:[String]?
        var v:String?
        var answerType:NHAnswerType?


        var optionsModelArray:[NH_OptionsModel] = []
        init(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

            guard   let question = dictionary["question"] as? String,
                let typebutton = dictionary["button_type"] as? String,

                    let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
                 else {
                    return

            }
           // (myString as NSString).integerValue


            self.answerType = NHAnswerType(rawValue: Int(typebutton)!)
            print(self.answerType?.rawValue)


            if let options = dictionary["options"] as? [String]{
                print(options)

               print(options)


                for values in options{

                    print(values)

                    let optionmodel = NH_OptionsModel(values: values)
                    self.optionsModelArray.append(optionmodel)

                }


            }


            self.buttontype = typebutton
            self.question = question
            self.id = id

                       }

    }
```

In viewcontroller:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {



            super.viewDidLoad()

      self.tableview?.register(NH_SmileyCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: NH_SmileyCell.identifier)
            self.tableview?.register(NH_StarRatingCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: NH_StarRatingCell.identifier)
            self.tableview?.register(NH_CheckBoxCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: NH_CheckBoxCell.identifier)
            self.tableview?.register(NH_RadioTypeCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: NH_RadioTypeCell.identifier)
    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let model = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.row)
           // print(model.answerType?.hashValue)
            print(model.answerType)
            print(model.answerType?.rawValue)


            switch model.answerType {
            case .NHAnswerRadioButton?:
                if let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NH_RadioTypeCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? NH_RadioTypeCell {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = "dfdsfgs"
                  //  cell.item = item
                    return cell
                }
            case .NHAnswerCheckboxButton?:
                if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NH_CheckBoxCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? NH_CheckBoxCell {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = "dfdsfgs"
                    //  cell.item = item
                    return cell
                }
            case .NHAnswerSmileyButton?:
                if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NH_SmileyCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? NH_SmileyCell {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = "dfdsfgs"
                    //  cell.item = item
                    return cell
                }
            case .NHAnswerStarRatingButton?:
                if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NH_StarRatingCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? NH_StarRatingCell {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = "dfdsfgs"
                    //  cell.item = item
                    return cell
                }
    //        case .NHAnswerTextButton?:
    //            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NH_TextCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? NH_TextCell{
    //                //  cell.item = item
    //                return cell
    //            }
                default:
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
```

And in the radiotypecell:

```
 class NH_RadioTypeCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel?

        var item: NH_QuestionViewModelItem? {
            didSet {
                guard let item = item as? NHQuestionViewModelQuestionNameItem else {
                    return
                }

                questionLabel?.text = item.question

            }
        }


        static var nib:UINib {
            return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
        }

        static var identifier: String {
            return String(describing: self)
        }



        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

    }
```

This always produces the following error message:

> NH_CheckBoxCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or
>   connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

How can I fix the problem?

What changes should I do in while registration of the cell in the tableview in swift?

Comment: Are you using prototype cells? Why are `id`, `question`, `buttontype` and `answerType` optional? If the values pass the `guard let` check they are clearly always non-optional and you can get rid of many question and exclamation marks.

Comment: here i have 5 tableviewcell.So according to the type display the cell in tableview.How to do?

Comment: Once again: Are you using prototype cells or extra XIBs?

Comment: i am using xib......

Comment: Then triple check the nib names and the identifiers. And why is the table view optional, too?

Comment: did i need to give the identifier in the xib.

Comment: No, but according to your code the nib name is equal to the identifier.

Comment: yes but alawys showing the mention error .How to fix?

Comment: i not understanding how to fix it..please help?

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.